# Something causes a lot of initiatives

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I’m translating a movie about basic income, from French to English. In this movie, someone says that basic income would make people do a lot of new things, that it would create a lot of initiatives.

If anyone knows French, the exact words are "Il y aurait une floraison d’initiatives." (There would be a "flowering" of initiatives. I don’t think I can use "flowering" this way, in English, but I think you can see what is meant. It’s like, an explosion of initiatives, you see.)

So, I’m trying to put a word, or words, there, rather than "flowering". How would you say that?

Answer (score 1):

How about a *[deluge](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/deluge)* of initiatives?

> : an overwhelming amount or number

Comment: This is good too, it's similar to the other answer that disappeared (it was deleted?) "torrent of initiatives"… I’m not really sure which one I should choose…

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep to the botanical theme, you could consider *blossoming*, but you might want to change the structure to something like ‘Initiatives would blossom’.

Comment: The botanical theme isn't required. I’m simply looking for a something that has an identical/similar meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have seen "flowering" used that way before. You could also use "flourishing," which is etymologically related and which refers to growing, expanding, and thriving. It's usually an emotionally positive term that refers to fast but organic growth. A more extreme term would be "an *explosion* of initiatives," which would indicate chaotic, disorganized spending on all sorts of things at once, and which probably suggests that many would succeed and many would fail. "A *flourishing* of initiatives" suggests a process that's not quite as wild, but better thought-out.

Normally "flourishing" is an adjective and isn't used as a noun like that, but I think it can be. A possible substitute is "florescence," but that's an unusual word and people will probably confuse it with "fluorescence."

Comment: Mh, indeed, "flourishing" sounds positive. I found results for it too on Google. You said it isn't used as a noun like that, but I find it exactly used this way in results. Do you think it would be weird?

Comment: I think it's fine, personally.

Answer (score 0):

I like "flurry" myself.  Yes I do.